# Get the index of object in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

Just wanted to know if there is any method in NSMutableArray (or NSArray) which lets you get the index of a specific object? for example if have an array which has 
a b c d e f g h i objects how can I get the index for like c or e or any other object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) has methods along the lines of [indexOfObject:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB) that will give you the index of an object. It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Read through the documentation at the links provided and you should find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Have you already tried with `indexOfObject`? Just look for it in the docs and you'll find it ;-)